# Is it possible that React modifies a reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a small experiment with implementing an observer pattern manually in React (*). It basically works, but with a highly unexpected detail. Consider this minimal example:

```js
class Observer {
  constructor() {
    this.callbacks = [];
  }

  register(callback) {
    console.log("received callback register");
    this.callbacks.push(callback);
    console.log(`number of callbacks: ${this.callbacks.length}`);
  }

  call() {
    console.log(`calling ${this.callbacks.length} callbacks`);
    for (let callback of this.callbacks) {
      callback();
    }
  }
}

function Main() {
  const observer = useRef(new Observer());

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.current.call();
  }, [observer]);

  return <SubComponent observer={observer.current} />;
}

function SubComponent({ observer }) {
  console.log("registering observer");
  observer.register(() => {
    console.log("callback called");
  });
  return <div>Hello World</div>;
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-hill-mrd8n?file=/src/index.tsx:0-1045)

In the console log this produces:

```
registering observer
received callback register
number of callbacks: 1
calling 2 callbacks
callback called
callback called
```

As you can see, the number of registered callbacks has suddenly changed to 2, even though only 1 callback has been registered. How is this possible? Do I have a blind spot or is this somehow an implication of how React works?

---

(*) I know that this problem can be solved by a [combination of `useImperativeHandle` and `forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle). The above is just an experiment to investigate alternatives, and I'm asking for learning purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you put the register logic in render function (function component's body), it will register it on **every component's render**.

And since you have [`StrictMode` wrapper](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper), it invoked twice:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - ...
> - Function component bodies

You can either remove the `StrictMode` (not recommended) or write the logic in `useEffect` as I guess you want it registered on `observer` change:

```
function Main() {
  const observer = useRef(new Observer());

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.current.call();
  }, [observer]);

  return <SubComponent observer={observer.current} />;
}
```

[image: Edit patient-cache-emkoo]

Note that in StrictMode the logs are silenced, so you don't see the second `console.log("registering observer");`

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like `console.log()` to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions.

Comment: But the component only gets rendered once, doesn't it? Shouldn't I see multiple `console.log` messages if the function body gets evaluated twice?

Comment: In production yes, it will render once, but you really should write such logic in `useEffect`, registering on every render doesn't make sense

Comment: In this case, React disables logs in the second render, 
check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0db61a08befe6406aa93568708224d1cca2aff7d/packages/shared/ConsolePatchingDev.js)

Comment: In StrictMode the logs are silenced, read the **NOTES** in link shared in the answer

Comment: Damn this was a great question and answer.

Comment: @Zac That explains a lot, thanks! So what confused me is the fact `console.log` is no longer a plain `console.log` in React (dev mode I guess).